# Can indices save a giant `WHERE foo IN (...)` query with thousands of entries in the query list?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have some client code hitting my postgres instance with a giant `SELECT` statement that is matching against a list of IDs.  The query ends up looking like this...

```
SELECT "id","name","status","regionid" FROM "public"."store" WHERE "regionid" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$60,$61,$62,$63,$64,$65,$66,$67,$68,$69,$70,$71,$72,$73,$74,$75,$76,$77,$78,$79,$80,$81,$82,$83,$84,$85,$86,$87,$88,$89,$90,$91,$92,$93,$94,$95,$96,$97,$98,$99,$100,$101,$102,$103,$104,$105,$106,$107,$108,$109,$110,$111,$112,$113,$114,$115,$116,$117,$118,$119,$120,$121,$122,$123,$124,$125,$126,$127,$128,$129,$130,$131,$132,$133,$134,$135,$136,$137,$138,$139,$140,$141,$142,$143,$144,$145,$146,$147,$148,$149,$150,$151,$152,$153,$154,$155,$156,$157,$158,$159,$160,$161,$162,$163,$164,$165,$166,$167,$168,$169,$170,$171,$172,$173,$174,$175,$176,$177,$178,$179,$180,$181,$182,$183,$184,$185,$186,$187,$188,$189,$190,$191,$192,$193,$194,$195,$196,$197,$198,$199,$200,$201,$202,$203,$204,$205,$206,$207,$208,$209,$210,$211,$212,$213,$214,$215,$216,$217,$218,$219,$220,$221,$222,$223,$224,$225,$226,$227,$228,$229,$230,$231,$232,$233,$234,$235,$236,$237,$238,$239,$240,$241,$242,$243,$244,$245,$246,$247,$248,$249,$250,$251,$252,$253,$254,$255,$256,$257,$258,$259,$260,$261,$262,$263,$264,$265,$266,$267,$268,$269,$270,$271,$272,$273,$274,$275,$276,$277,$278,$279,$280,$281,$282,$283,$284,$285,$286,$287,$288,$289,$290,$291,$292,$293,$294,$295,$296,$297,$298,$299,$300,$301,$302,$303,$304,$305,$306,$307,$308,$309,$310,$311,$312,$313,$314,$315,$316,$317,$318,$319,$320,$321,$322,$323,$324,$325,$326,$327,$328,$329,$330,$331,$332,$333,$334,$335,$336,$337,$338,$339,$340,$341,$342,$343,$344,$345,$346,$347,$348,$349,$350,$351,$352,$353,$354,$355,$356,$357,$358,$359,$360,$361,$362,$363,$364,$365,$366,$367,$368,$369,$370,$371,$372,$373,$374,$375,$376,$377,$378,$379,$380,$381,$382,$383,$384,$385,$386,$387,$388,$389,$390,$391,$392,$393,$394,$395,$396,$397,$398,$399,$400,$401,$402,$403,$404,$405,$406,$407,$408,$409,$410,$411,$412,$413,$414,$415,$416,$417,$418,$419,$420,$421,$422,$423,$424,$425,$426,$427,$428,$429,$430,$431,$432,$433,$434,$435,$436,$437,$438,$439,$440,$441,$442,$443,$444,$445,$446,$447,$448,$449,$450,$451,$452,$453,$454,$455,$456,$457,$458,$459,$460,$461,$462,$463,$464,$465,$466,$467,$468,$469,$470,$471,$472,$473,$474,$475,$476,$477,$478,$479,$480,$481,$482,$483,$484,$485,$486,$487,$488,$489,$490,$491,$492,$493,$494,$495,$496,$497,$498,$499,$500,$501,$502,$503,$504,$505,$506,$507,$508,$509,$510,$511,$512,$513,$514,$515,$516,$517,$518,$519,$520,$521,$522,$523,$524,$525,$526,$527,$528,$529,$530,$531,$532,$533,$534,$535,$536,$537,$538,$539,$540,$541,$542,$543,$544,$545,$546,$547,$548,$549,$550,$551,$552,$553,$554,$555,$556,$557,$558,$559,$560,$561,$562,$563,$564,$565,$566,$567,$568,$569,$570,$571,$572,$573,$574,$575,$576,$577,$578,$579,$580,$581,$582,$583,$584,$585,$586,$587,$588,$589,$590,$591,$592,$593,$594,$595,$596,$597,$598,$599,$600,$601,$602,$603,$604,$605,$606,$607,$608,$609,$610,$611,$612,$613,$614,$615,$616,$617,$618,$619,$620,$621,$622,$623,$624,$625,$626,$627,$628,$629,$630,$631,$632,$633,$634,$635,$636,$637,$638,$639,$640,$641,$642,$643,$644,$645,$646,$647,$648,$649,$650,$651,$652,$653,$654,$655,$656,$657,$658,$659,$660,$661,$662,$663,$664,$665,$666,$667,$668,$669,$670,$671,$672,$673,$674,$675,$676,$677,$678,$679,$680,$681,$682,$683,$684,$685,$686,$687,$688,$689,$690,$691,$692,$693,$694,$695,$696,$697,$698,$699,$700,$701,$702,$703,$704,$705,$706,$707,$708,$709,$710,$711,$712,$713,$714,$715,$716,$717,$718,$719,$720,$721,$722,$723,$724,$725,$726,$727,$728,$729,$730,$731,$732,$733,$734,$735,$736,$737,$738,$739,$740,$741,$742,$743,$744,$745,$746,$747,$748,$749,$750,$751,$752,$753,$754,$755,$756,$757,$758,$759,$760,$761,$762,$763,$764,$765,$766,$767,$768,$769,$770,$771,$772,$773,$774,$775,$776,$777,$778,$779,$780,$781,$782,$783,$784,$785,$786,$787,$788,$789,$790,$791,$792,$793,$794,$795,$796,$797,$798,$799,$800,$801,$802,$803,$804,$805,$806,$807,$808,$809,$810,$811,$812,$813,$814,$815,$816,$817,$818,$819,$820,$821,$822,$823,$824,$825,$826,$827,$828,$829,$830,$831,$832,$833,$834,$835,$836,$837,$838,$839,$840,$841,$842,$843,$844,$845,$846,$847,$848,$849,$850,$851,$852,$853,$854,$855,$856,$857,$858,$859,$860,$861,$862,$863,$864,$865,$866,$867,$868,$869,$870,$871,$872,$873,$874,$875,$876,$877,$878,$879,$880,$881,$882,$883,$884,$885,$886,$887,$888,$889,$890,$891,$892,$893,$894,$895,$896,$897,$898,$899,$900,$901,$902,$903,$904,$905,$906,$907,$908,$909,$910,$911,$912,$913,$914,$915,$916,$917,$918,$919,$920,$921,$922,$923,$924,$925,$926,$927,$928,$929,$930,$931,$932,$933,$934,$935,$936,$937,$938,$939,$940,$941,$942,$943,$944,$945,$946,$947,$948,$949,$950,$951,$952,$953,$954,$955,$956,$957,$958,$959,$960,$961,$962,$963,$964,$965,$966,$967,$968,$969,$970,$971,$972,$973,$974,$975,$976,$977,$978,$979,$980,$981,$982,$983,$984,$985,$986,$987,$988,$989,$990,$991,$992,$993,$994,$995,$996,$997,$998,$999,$1000,$1001,$1002,$1003,$1004,$1005,$1006,$1007,$1008) ORDER BY "id" [ '00178340-4467-11e6-8a37-219b2acdc346',
  '003be4e0-0260-11e6-af27-2d5012c820c0',
  '006a6460-db4f-11e5-9c34-e3c0bb24c767',
  // snip ]
```

It seems like this query is especially slow.  My initial intuition is to just slap an index on `regionid` within the `store` table, but I wonder if the database will really continue to scale as the number of `regionid` elements that are queried over grows over time.

What is the typical way to scale this over time?  Will a simple index on `regionid` scalably save me going forwards, or is the `WHERE IN` ultimately going to be a crux?

EDIT: Here is the result of an `EXPLAIN` query on a shortened dataset:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Startup Cost": 211.01,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Startup Cost": 34.7,
          "Plan Width": 110,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Plan Width": 0,
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Index Cond": "(store.regionid = ANY ('{00178340-4467-11e6-8a37-219b2acdc346,003be4e0-0260-11e6-af27-2d5012c820c0,006a6460-db4f-11e5-9c34-e3c0bb24c767,00811b60-4d37-11e6-80df-5b5d32d23050,008d2270-8694-11e6-9802-ed42b1afc98c,014d2350-4d4a-11e6-b004-9d13a9078e9a,01516370-94a3-11e6-8ece-0f437fd4c46e,015654a0-4874-11e6-8a37-219b2acdc346}'::text[]))",
              "Plan Rows": 55,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Index Name": "unique_stores",
              "Total Cost": 34.69
            }
          ],
          "Recheck Cond": "(store.regionid = ANY ('{00178340-4467-11e6-8a37-219b2acdc346,003be4e0-0260-11e6-af27-2d5012c820c0,006a6460-db4f-11e5-9c34-e3c0bb24c767,00811b60-4d37-11e6-80df-5b5d32d23050,008d2270-8694-11e6-9802-ed42b1afc98c,014d2350-4d4a-11e6-b004-9d13a9078e9a,01516370-94a3-11e6-8ece-0f437fd4c46e,015654a0-4874-11e6-8a37-219b2acdc346}'::text[]))",
          "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
          "Plan Rows": 55,
          "Relation Name": "store",
          "Alias": "store",
          "Output": [
            "id",
            "name",
            "status",
            "regionid",
            "storeid"
          ],
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Total Cost": 209.42,
          "Schema": "public"
        }
      ],
      "Sort Key": [
        "store.id",
        "store.storeid"
      ],
      "Plan Rows": 55,
      "Node Type": "Sort",
      "Output": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "status",
        "regionid",
        "storeid"
      ],
      "Plan Width": 110,
      "Total Cost": 211.15
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How many distinct `regionid` values are in the `store` table?  If the application is listing out 1000 regions and there are only 1500 regions in total, it's almost certainly going to be faster to do a table scan than to use an index on `regionid`.  If there are 150,000 different regions, on the other hand, using an index on `regionid` would almost certainly be more efficient even if the list grew to a few thousand entries.

Comment: Separate from that, though, long before I got to 1000 elements, I'd seriously think about loading the regions I want to search into a temp table  or some other structure so that I wasn't generating thousands of different queries that differed only by the number of bind variables in the `IN` list.

Comment: @JustinCave There is a typical ratio of about 20 stores per region...so it will scale ~20:1.  With respect to your second comment, I'll have to do some reading up on that one.

Comment: For some context (I am still trying to sort this out, myself a bit!), it appears that a client ORM is generating this query through a permissions check.  So, a user has permission (enforced at an application level) to access stores from regions with those IDs, and then they are querying for the accessible stores through this `WHERE IN` query (generated with an ORM)

Comment: That's not the ratio to be concerned with.  It doesn't matter whether there are 1, 10, 100, or 1000 stores per region.  The important question is what fraction of the rows in the table the query is returning.  If there are tens or hundreds of thousands of regions, then an IN list with 1000 regions is only going to return a few percent of the rows in the table and an index would make sense.  If the query is going to return most of the rows in the table because the IN list is so long, then an index won't be helpful.

Comment: Care to post the current execution plan? Can't say about Postgres for sure, but some other databases would resolve such queries by building implicit temp tables to hold the `IN` list values and performing a join, so there a good (possibly covering) index _would_ help.

Comment: @mustaccio Hopefully I captured the data you were asking about, appended it to the end of my question.  I cut the test query down to a handful of ids for it

Comment: @JustinCave I see what you're saying.  Honestly, for a lot of users this query is going to contain ~90% of the values, so maybe the index won't help by your reasoning.

Comment: Well, it's already doing a [bitmap] index scan, innit?

Comment: look for a way to use an array instead of individual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Very often joining against a `VALUES` list is faster than using an IN condition:

```
SELECT id, name, status, regionid 
FROM public.store 
  JOIN (
    VALUES ($1), ($2), ($3), ($4), ($5), .... , ($1000) )
  ) as x(id) on x.id = store.regionid
ORDER by store.id;
```

An index on `store (regionid)` typically helps there

Answer (score 0):

Since Postgres 9.2 index-only scan is supported so, in answer to your question whether an index can help in this situation, I think it definitely might.

Instead of just indexing the `regionid` field, create an index on `(regionid, id, name, status)` and the query can scan the index instead of the table. Assuming that the table has many more fields than just those four, then this operation should be much quicker.

Don't forget to test whether this impacts on the `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` operations.

[More info at Use The Index Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)

Comment: @Jim this was an interesting question and I'm keen to hear back whether my proposed solution was any help. Could you share your findings?